# Jittery camera movement in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making an endless runner game like temple run. The camera follows the player at an offset. When the camera gets too close to the player, the jitteriness becomes very obvious. I think when the camera is far away from the player(at the very start of the game, when the offset has not been reached), it's still jittery.

How can I resolve the jitteriness?

The code for  camera:

```
private void Start()
    {
        tempPos = target.position;
        offset = transform.position - target.position;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {

        Vector3 followPos = target.position - target.forward * trailDistance;
        followPos.y += heightOffset;
        tempPos += (followPos - transform.position) * cameraDelay;
        //var targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(target.transform.position - transform.position);
        //transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        Vector3 smoothedPosition = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, tempPos, ref velocity, smoothSpeed);
        transform.position = smoothedPosition;
        transform.LookAt(target.transform);
   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to do this that I use. It also has an awesome smooth/delay effect. This is also what you would use in a Multiplayer Scenario when the code is really jittery due to lag.

```
float delay = 2f;// Play around with me

void FixedUpdate() 
{
    Vector3 followPos = target.position - target.forward * trailDistance;
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, followPos, delay);
}
```